# inject a DIV container in the DOM with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I wonder how I create a container around elements in the DOM with javascript? I have had success with injecting DIVs straght in the html before, but need to target a couple elements and place them inside a container and unsure how to.

This is the html:

```
<div class="menubar">
  <div class="searching myClass yourClass"></div>
  <ul class="navVoordelen">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
  <a class="navLogo"></a>
  <div class="langsel"></div>
  <a class="navLogin"></a>
  <a class="navLogin"></a>
  <a class="navLogin"></a>
  <ul class="newnav clearfix animated">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I need to place the container below the parent Menubar DIV and have it end before the second UL class. This is what i want it to looks like:

```
<div class="menubar">
  <div div="container">
    <div class="searching myClass yourClass"></div>
    <ul class="navVoordelen">
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
    <a class="navLogo"></a>
    <div class="langsel"></div>
    <a class="navLogin"></a>
    <a class="navLogin"></a>
    <a class="navLogin"></a>
  </div>
  <ul class="newnav clearfix animated">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: you got a typo `div div="container"`

Comment: Are you using any libs like `jquery` or `prototype` etc? Or just vanilla JS. Will make it easier to answer if we know this. :)

Comment: Hi! I can only use vanilla JS unfortunaly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest the following approach:

```js
function wrapAllPrevious() {
  // this is assigned via the Function.prototype.call()
  // method, later:
  var _self = this,
      // creating a <div> element:
      div = document.createElement('div');
  // assigning an 'id' to that created-<div>:
  div.id = 'demo';

  // inserting the created-<div> before the _self/this
  // element, using insertBefore():
  _self.parentNode.insertBefore(div, _self);
  // while the created-<div> has a previousSibling:
  while (div.previousSibling) {
    // we insert that previous-sibling before firstChild
    // of the <div> (effectively prepending the element
    // to the created-<div>):
    div.insertBefore(div.previousSibling, div.firstChild);
  }
}

// calling the function, using (as noted earlier)
// Function.prototype.call() to assign the specified
// <ul> as the 'this' of the function (using
// document.querySelector() to return the specific node:
wrapAllPrevious.call(document.querySelector('ul.newnav.clearfix.animated'));
```

```css
#demo {
  border: 2px solid #f00;
}

#demo::before {
  content: "Newly-added <div> element.";
}
```

```html
<div class="menubar">
  <div class="searching myClass yourClass"></div>
  <ul class="navVoordelen">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
  <a class="navLogo"></a>
  <div class="langsel"></div>
  <a class="navLogin"></a>
  <a class="navLogin"></a>
  <a class="navLogin"></a>
  <ul class="newnav clearfix animated">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

References:

- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelector).
- [`Node.insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore).
- [`Node.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node.parentNode).
- [`Node.previousSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node.previousSibling).
- [`while` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code in javascript

```
var div = '<div class="container">';
var closediv = '</div>';
theParent =document.getElementsByClassName("menubar");
theParent.insertBefore(div, theParent.firstChild);

document.getElementsByClassName("menubar").appendChild(closediv);
```

Comment: No, you cannot append starting and closing tags that way.